How is the Task<TResult> constructed in async methods under .NET Core
After reading this otherwise very in-depth blog post, I still cannot understand how the Task<TResult> is really constructed before it is returned from the async method.
I get how the compiled method initializes and runs the state machine for the first time. Then if the first await is not already completed, it registers a continuation for it to the MoveNext() method that is currently running and then returns from it to the compiled method.
At this point the compiled method returns builder.Task<TResult>.
I get a bit of the magic behind it by browsing the source code, i.e. it being an instance of the Task derived AsyncStateMachineBox<TStateMachine> but I do not understand what this task represents when it is first constructed.
Is it the continuation we just registered with the first thing to be awiated? But then what if there are other awaits that need their own continuation tasks?

The best way to learn what code is generated by the compiler - to write several versions of async Task (with one, two, three await points in body) and view result code in sharplab.io

"Is it the continuation we just registered ... ?" - what is "it" in that question? The task that gets returned represents the overall async method's progression and hopefully completion - if multiple incomplete await are involved, multiple continuations back to the in-flight state machine will be attached, with the task's completion being signalled by the completion of the state machine

No, wrong mental model.  The .NET framework code doesn't help you, you have to look at the code that the C# compiler generates in MoveNext().  It is quite ugly, try ildasm.exe or a poor quality decompiler.

Why are you interested about this implementation detail? How is this information going to help you in writing better asynchronous code? If it's just a curiosity question, you could mention it in the body of the question. Any answer you might get will become obsolete as soon as the next .NET runtime version is released, because there is nothing stopping Microsoft from changing the implementation of the async state machine from the one .NET version to the next.

@MarcGravell the what is "it" is my question albeit poorly formulated. What happens when we call Wait() on the Task that just got returned from the async method? How is this task-derived object signalled by the state machine it encapsulates - is it just the SetResult at the end of it?

@tinmanjk assuming it actually went async (which isn't guaranteed), and that it ran to completion: sure.

@HansPassant well trying ILSpy 8.2 with .NET 6 produces
<>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter2, ref stateMachine);
at every relevant step which can call Task.UnsafeSetContinuationForAwait. Now this is where I don't understand what's really going on. We can register stateMachineBox itself as continuation sometimes, othertimes its MoveNextAction.

@TheodorZoulias from the article I mentioned:
"While it’s common to use this support without knowing exactly what’s happening under the hood, I’m a firm believer that understanding how something actually works helps you to make even better use of it. For async/await in particular, understanding the mechanisms involved is especially helpful when you want to look below the surface,"

@MarcGravell yeah, assuming worst case scenario. Multiple awaiters that don't complete right away. So, the callback behind the statemachinebox task is the MoveNext() method which is registered as a continuation with each successive task we await and is triggered multiple times before it produces the side effect of setting the result of the task?

basically, yes, although it isn't assumed that the things we're awaiting are tasks - nor does the result need necessarily to be a task; the ability to await and be awaited is a pattern, of which Task[<T>] is just one (albeit very common) implementation

Thanks to the comments (esp by Marc Gravell) and the hints from this accompanying video to the originally referenced blog-post (e.g. that the logic for asynchronous operations using tasks is split across two types Task<TResult> (consumer) and TaskCompletionSource<TResult> (producer) following the producer-consumer pattern), I think I can answer my own question (any comments welcome).
From the comments in the source code of TaskCompletionSource<TResult>:

Represents the producer side of a 
unbound to a delegate, providing access to the consumer side through the  property.
It enables the creation of a task that can be handed out to consumers,
and those consumers can use the members of the task as they would any
other. However, unlike most tasks, the state of a task created by a
TaskCompletionSource is controlled explicitly by the methods on
TaskCompletionSource. This enables the completion of the external
asynchronous operation to be propagated to the underlying Task. The
separation also ensures that consumers are not able to transition the
state without access to the corresponding TaskCompletionSource.

What's interesting is that the task is "unbound to a delegate". This was my original confusion, thinking that tasks are always bound to some form of a delegate.
However, the C# compiler doesn't use TaskCompletionSource<TResult> but AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<TResult> for implementing this pattern.
They are very similar in what they do having methods such as
public void SetResult(TResult result)

public void SetException(Exception exception)

If one is to decompile the state machine that is generated from the async method, the end of the MoveNext() method makes use of those.
catch (Exception exception)
{
    <>1__state = -2;
    <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
    return;
}
<>1__state = -2;
<>t__builder.SetResult();

These methods do the actual signalling/unblocking if we for some reason decide to Wait() on the Task that we receive back from an async method.
To answer my original questions

but I do not understand what this task represents when it is first
constructed.

the AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<TResult> type creates a brand new unbound (see above)Task<TResult> for the async method (as a derived type AsyncStateMachineBox<TStateMachine> instance  This is done mostly for optimizations/stack-vs-heap considerations).

Is it the continuation we just registered with the first thing to be
awiated? But then what if there are other awaits that need their own
continuation tasks?

No. We register the state machine's MoveNext() callback as continuation for each asynchronous operation we await. Once all asynchronous operations have completed and we are at the end of the state machine's MoveNext() code we manually call SetResult or SetException to complete the task that we constructed to track the success of the whole operation. The task is not updated at intermediate steps, i.e. after each check point. It just represents the end result.
